# Gradle build failing

Tags: docker, gradle

My gradle build is failing when trying to run on a docker container.

> Could not build image: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory"

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.09.1-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   19e2cf6
 Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:24:48 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.1-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   19e2cf6
 Built:        Thu Dec  7 22:23:29 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Comment: Note to moderators: this is 100% on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just to explain the downvotes: the content of the question does not correlate with the question name at all. The error says that the author cannot run the shell program in Docker, and the question name states that the author cannot build something using Gradle. It is not shown **where** Gradle is in the problem. Is it Gradle in Docker failing to start? Or is it Docker build started by Gradle as a sub-task? Or is it Docker building Gradle itself? No MCVE, no clear explanations, no any sign of attempt to understand the problem before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the [docker Gradle image](https://hub.docker.com/_/gradle) (whose [Dockerfile](https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/master/jre12/Dockerfile) points to [`AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker)) includes a /bin/sh, the error message might comes from [issue 1396](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396)

[From this comment](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1396#issuecomment-456244847), assuming you don't have any data issue from a "work in progress", this should be enough:

```
docker system --prune --all
```